# MongoDB Type Order

Tags: mongodb

I have this collection in MongoDB. It contains
values of different types under the val key.
Also, note that I am sorting it by val ascending.

```
[test] 2014-02-20 08:53:11.857 >>> db.account.find().sort({val:1});
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5304d25786dd4b348bcc2b2e"),
        "username" : "usr10",
        "password" : "123",
        "val" : [ ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5304d29986dd4b348bcc2b2f"),
        "username" : "usr20",
        "password" : "456",
        "val" : null
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5304e31686dd4b348bcc2b37"),
        "username" : "usr80",
        "password" : "555",
        "val" : 1
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5304d50a86dd4b348bcc2b32"),
        "username" : "usr50",
        "password" : "555",
        "val" : [
                40
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5304d4c886dd4b348bcc2b31"),
        "username" : "usr40",
        "password" : "777",
        "val" : 200
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5304d2a186dd4b348bcc2b30"),
        "username" : "usr30",
        "password" : "888",
        "val" : {

        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5304d97786dd4b348bcc2b33"),
        "username" : "usr50",
        "password" : "555",
        "val" : {
                "ok" : 1
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5304e2dc86dd4b348bcc2b36"),
        "username" : "usr80",
        "password" : "555",
        "val" : true
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5304e22f86dd4b348bcc2b34"),
        "username" : "usr60",
        "password" : "555",
        "val" : ISODate("2014-02-19T16:56:15.787Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5304e2c786dd4b348bcc2b35"),
        "username" : "usr70",
        "password" : "555",
        "val" : /abc/
}
[test] 2014-02-20 08:53:19.357 >>>
```

I am reading a book which says the following.

*MongoDB has a hierarchy as to how types compare. Sometimes you will have

a single key with multiple types: for instance, integers and booleans, or strings

and nulls. If you do a sort on a key with a mix of types, there is a predefined

order that they will be sorted in. From least to greatest value, this ordering

is as follows:

1. Minimum value

2. null

3. Numbers (integers, longs, doubles)

4. Strings

5. Object/document

6. Array

7. Binary data

8. Object ID

9. Boolean

10. Date

11. Timestamp

12. Regular expression

13. Maximum value*

So why is my sorting order different? For example,
when I sort (see above) I see these strange things:

1) I have no idea what 'minimum value' and 'maximum value' mean.

2) An array comes before a number. And an empty
   array comes even before null.

3) The number 1 comes before an array

4) The array [40] comes between numbers 1 and 200.

Could someone just explain this result in some details?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your book says the same as the [official documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/). But this also does not explain the obscure sorting order of the two arrays. At least the two types `Minimum value` and `Maximum value` are explained. They are internal.

Comment: Thanks for the initial feedback, I will keep monitoring the answers to this question I posted.

Answer (score 2):

The type order is only used when there isn't another supported way of ordering elements.  Array fields have their own sorting behavior where the minimum value of their elements are used on an ascending sort, and the maximum value on a descending sort.  The type of *that* minimum or maximum value is then used to order the docs with fields of that type.

So `[40]` comes after `1`, but before `200` because the minimum value of that array is `40`.

The empty array has no value at all, which is why it ends up with the doc where the value is `null`.  If I reverse the sort, they stay in the same order which implies that MongoDB considers them equal.

Comment: "Array fields have their own sorting behavior where the minimum value of their elements are used on an ascending sort, and the maximum value on a descending sort." This is a very good thing to know. I tried it, really it behaves that way. How about that empty array? Does it really treat it as null?

Comment: @peter.petrov I haven't looked at the source code to know for sure, but that's what the empirical evidence of trying it suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the sort clause in your query? Your sort order appears to be the default order - notice the ascending ObjectIds. You mentioned you're sorting by `val` so I would expect your query to be

`db.account.find({val:1})`

Comment: Sorry, I changed that later. Let me post the exact thing now.

Comment: OK, the strange things are less now but still there.

Answer (score 0):

## MongoDB type comparison

### Why

MongoDB is a schemaless database, which allows you to store pieces of information (document) without defining a structure (schema of fields), like in SQL where we have to define a schema in the form of columns and their data types.

In the case of sorting or data retrival this may be problematic. In order to be predictable, MongoDB has a fixed type order to sort documents of different types as you already mentioned:

1. Minimum value (MinKey)
2. Null
3. Numbers (ints, longs, doubles, decimals)
4. Strings
5. Object/document
6. Array
7. Binary data
8. ObjectId
9. Boolean
10. Date
11. Timestamp
12. Regex
13. Maximum value (MaxKey)

In the process of sorting values get compared, in order to decide how they should be positioned.
This list defines from lowest to highest what should happen when theses data types get compared.

```
{ "a": 0 }
{ "a": "a" }
{ "a": 1 }
```

When sorted by a ascending numbers precide strings, as the list states Strings (4) and Numbers (3).

### Conversions

For certain data types MongoDB tries to convert them when compared (If you know JavaScript this should feel familiar).

```
[] -> null
[[]] -> Array

// but
"" -> String
0 -> Number
...
```

For one dimensional Arrays, their conversions depend on the order of sorting.

```
// ascending
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] (Array) -> 1 (Int)
[5, 8, 10] (Array) -> 5 (Int)

// descending
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] (Array) -> 5 (Int)
[5, 8, 10] (Array) -> 10 (Int)
```

### MinKey / MaxKey

MinKey is the lowest possible value in every comparison, MaxKey the highest. Both are used internally, as they are always at the beginning or end of a collection when sorted.

### Questions

1. *I have no idea what 'minimum value' and 'maximum value' mean.*

These are MinKey and MaxKey. See above.

2. *An array comes before a number. And an empty array comes even before null.*

It does not. As already explained an [] is always converted to null. When comparing equal values like, null and null or 40 and [40], the documents are sorted by natural order, which is in your case the timestamp in the ObjectId.
Try creating first the null entry and then the empty array.

3. *The number 1 comes before an array*

`[40]` is not an Array since it's converted to a Number. `[[40]]` would be an Array.

4. *The array [40] comes between numbers 1 and 200.*

If think you've got it. See 3.

### Sources and further reading

- https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb/mongodb-data-types.php
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/